# Can the WebNFC API be used to pass messages between phones?

Tags: android, webnfc

The WebNFC API seems like it makes it possible to read and write text between devices.

However, when I tried to read/write between phones using this website:
https://nfctools.net/

The phone vibrates, but then I get the error `NotSupportedError`:
There is no NFC adapter compatible with Web NFC, or the available NFC adapter does not support pushing messages, or connection can not be established.

Is the limitation of the protocol, the web api, or just my phone?

Comment: Could you share the exact message you got in the dev tool console log? The WebNFC API on android should work. Also it would be helpful if you can share the NFC tag info and the phone info.